# FormView FindControl not able to convert ToInt32

Tags: c#

I have a class Cust_Result that accepts an integer parameter.

So on my main page when it loads I bind a formview to display the data that I retrieved. Now I would like to extract the value of my "id" label and assign it to a variable which I can than pass to my Cust_Result class but I keep receiving this error

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'."

I am assuming it is because I am trying to send a string value to a parameter that is wanting an integer value but I am unsure on how to do the conversion.

My code

```
 int cust;

       cust = (Convert.ToInt32(FormView1.Row.FindControl("ID")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a string to convert and that's the `Label.Text` property (not just the Label).

I'll split it into 2 steps:

```
Label lbl = FormView1.Row.FindControl("ID") as Label;
// option to bail out when lbl == null 
cust = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked appreciate the help will accept when it allows me to

Answer (score 1):

First convert the control to a Label

```
var label = (Label)FormView1.Row.FindControl("ID");
```

Then you can get the value in the label:

```
var cust = int.Parse(label.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the compiler error closely - it doesn't say anything about `string` and `int` - it's talking about `IConvertible` and `Label` - although the fact that it mentions `Label` instead of `Control` suggests that's not the code you've actually posted. `Convert.ToInt32` doesn't konw what to do with a `Control` or a `Label` - in this case, I believe you want the *text* of the label, so I'd write this:

```
 Label label = (Label) FormView1.Row.FindControl("ID");
 // Potentially check for "label" being null here, i.e. the control wasn't found
 int cust = Convert.ToInt32(label.Text);
```

It's not entirely clear where this value came from, but you may want to consider using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, too.

I'd also note that `Cust_Result` is an unconventional name - try to:

- Avoid abbreviations (Cust means Customer, I assume?)
- Don't use underscores
- Try to give more *meaningful* names - even `CustomerResult` doesn't really explain what it's the result *of*.